# Access components in View class from onTap method

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have a MapView and a set of markers on it, I also have a customized ItemizedOverlay class to handle map onTap event. Now, Lets say that I have the MapView in MainMap class and its corresponding CustomItemizedOverlay class. Is there any way to access the components (Eg: change visibility of a button in MainMap class) of the MainMap class from CustomItemizedOverlay's onTap() function??

On googling I came across this,
            View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.MAIN_MAP_LAYOUT, false);
and using view.findViewById() to access the components.
Is this a good idea or is there any other better way to access them.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the view you want to access to the Itemized overlay during instantiation (changing the constructor to accept one more parameter) or adding a method to your itmemized overlay to pass the view.

Example:

```
private View mView;

setViewToChange(View myView){
  this.mView = myView;
}
```

Regards.